# Multiple threads in db2luw

Tags: db2

I am very new to Db2. I have a question , Developed few procedures which will perform some operations on db2 database. My question is how to create multiple threads on db2 server concurrently. I mean I have a database with 70,000 tables each having more than 1000 records . I have a procedure which will update all these 70,000 tables. So time consumption is the main factor, here. I want to divide my update statement into 10 threads , where each thread will update 7000 tables. I want to run all the 10 threads simultaneously.

Can some one kindly let me know the way , to achieve this.
DB2 c Express on windows.

Comment: This seems like an application design nightmare.  Why do you have 70,000 tables that all need the "same" operation?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in DB2 for creating multiple threads.

The enterprise level version of DB2 will automatically  process a single statement across multiple cores when  and where needed.  But that's not what you're asking for.

I don't believe any SQL based RDBMS allows for a SP that create it's own threads.  The whole point of SQL is hat it's a higher level of abstraction, you don't have access to those kinds of details.

You'll need to write an external app in a language that supports threads and that opens 10 connections to the DB simultaneously.   But depending on the specifics of the update you're doing, and hardware you have.  You might find that 10 connections is too many.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Charles's correct answer, it is up to the client application to parallelize its DML workload by opening multiple connections to the database. You could write such a program on your own, but many [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load#Parallel_processing) utilities provide components that enable parallel workflows similar to what you've described. Aside from reduced programming, another advantage of using an ETL tool to define and manage a multi-threaded database update is built-in exception handling, making it easier to roll back all of the involved connections if any of them encounter an error.